# Why are pictures not showing up in JavaScript Toggle?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to put these images in the Hide/Show toggle of the content of this website as an example for those who use the tutorial website. However, everytime that I enter the pictures into the body of the "hide/show" block, it doesn't hide, it is always visible and the button for Hide/Show doesn't do anything. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("p").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<title>Homeroom GPA Calculatiion: Step 1</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hayes_java_project.css">
  <script src="gpa_calculation.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- Nav -->
<nav>
  <ul class="links">
    <li><a href="hayes_java_project.html">Home: GPA Calculation Tutorial</a></li>
    <li><a href="project_why.html"> Why Calculate your GPA?</a></li>
    <li><a href="project_step_1.html">Step 1: Document Your Grades</a></li>
    <li><a href="project_step_2.html">Step 2: Convert Grade Percentages to GPA Points</a></li>
    <li><a href="project_step_3.html">Step 3: Average GPA Point Total to Get GPA</a></li>
    <li><a href="project_step_4.html">Step 4: Submit GPA for Teachers</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<h1>HHHS Homeroom GPA Calculation: Step 1</h1>
<h2>Document Your Grades</h2>
<p>For this step, you will need your paper and writing utensil. Go to HomeAccess through the CPS portal and write down your 7 classes (not including homeroom) with the percentage of your current grade. See example below. </p>


<body>

  <button>Examples of Step 1 Here.</button>

  <p>Write down all classes. <img src="example1.png" alt="Write Down all of your current classes on paper" height="400" width="300" class="center"></p>
  <p>Document percentage points for each. <img src="example1.png" alt="Write Down all of your current classes on paper" height="400" width="300" class="center"></p>

</body>


<footer><small><i>Page created by Samantha Hayes.<br>
        Copyright &copy; 2018 <br>
        Please <a href="mailto:shayes@cpsk12.org">e-mail</a> me with any questions.<br>
        Last updated on December 2018. </i></small>
</footer>
<p>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `footer` should be inside the `body` tag

Comment: What Yosvel said. Also, you have an unclosed <p> tag right underneath said footer.

Comment: Might wanna check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if your jQuery selector is set up as it is now with `$("p").toggle();` that you will hide ALL of the p-tags in your document which is probably not what you want.

It is better to set up a selector like `$(".hide").toggle();` and then wrap a div with that class around all the content you wish to hide like so:

```
<div class="hide">
  <p>Write down all classes. <img src="example1.png" alt="Write Down all of your current classes on paper" height="400" width="300" class="center"></p>
  <p>Document percentage points for each. <img src="example1.png" alt="Write Down all of your current classes on paper" height="400" width="300" class="center"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery link is not working properly and providing errors:
Try this link and pattern:

```
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="hayes_java_project.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="gpa_calculation.js"></script>
</head>
```

Jquery code is working fine.

And html content as ( hide single p at first to toggle ):

```
<p>Write down all classes. <img src="example1.png" alt="Write Down all of your current classes on paper" height="400" width="300" class="center"></p>
<p style="display:none;">Document percentage points for each. <img src="example1.png" alt="Write Down all of your current classes on paper" height="400" width="300" class="center"></p>
```

Hope it helps.